# Como aplicar um estilo a um componente importado usando styled components

Tags: react-native, styled-components

Estou utilizando [este componente](https://github.com/benhurott/react-native-masked-text) para utilizar um input com máscara no meu aplicativo, porém eu gostaria que ele tivesse o mesmo estilo que o meu Input no meu styled-components:

```
const Input = styled.TextInput`
  paddingHorizontal: 20px;
  paddingVertical: 15px;
  borderRadius: 5px;
  backgroundColor: #fff;
  alignSelf: stretch;
  marginBottom: 15px;
  marginHorizontal: 20px;
  fontSize: 16px;
`;
```

Eu tentei algo como:

```
 const TextInputMask= styled.TextInputMask`
  paddingHorizontal: 20px;
  paddingVertical: 15px;
  borderRadius: 5px;
  backgroundColor: #fff;
  alignSelf: stretch;
  marginBottom: 15px;
  marginHorizontal: 20px;
  fontSize: 16px;
`;
```

Porém eu recebo:

> _styledComponents.dfault.TextInputMask is not a function. Components.default.TextInputMask is undefined

Comment: eu não consegui entender bem o que é "styled component", mas o textinputmask aceita style como props, basta vc colocar os estilos que quiser e vai funcionar

Comment: https://www.styled-components.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá,
você deve importar seu componente na sua pasta de `styled-components` e então exportar para o arquivo que deseja utilizar.

Ex: NA PASTA DO STYLED-COMPONENT

```
import {ComponenteImportado} from "ComponenteImportado";

export const NomeQueVoceQuer = styled(ComponenteImportado)
  paddingHorizontal: 20px;
  paddingVertical: 15px;
  borderRadius: 5px;
  backgroundColor: #fff;
  alignSelf: stretch;
  marginBottom: 15px;
  marginHorizontal: 20px;
  fontSize: 16px;
```

Agora é só importar o NomeQueVoceQuer para o arquivo que for usar.